# Set pager none in a view programmatically

Tags: views, 8

I want set pager none in a view programmatically, but I can not find a way to do it, the object "$view" does not seem to exhibit a way

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do something like:

```
$view->display_handler->options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
```

in your function. This calls the view's display handler to set the pager type option to 'none'.